# Return All Matching Values Based On One Lookup Value

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

The picture is showing the dataset that I have. The `ICTO_ID` in col `H` is repeating multiple times and it has more than one product, for example, `ICTO-247` has `Fx` and `eFX` as the `Product` (col `J`). Now in Col `E` (product) I need to show `ICTO-247` has `FX`, `eFX` as the `Product`. So Cell `E3` should read `FX`, `eFX`.

Now if I do a vlookup the only value returned will be `FX` as that is the first match based on `ICTO_ID`. I need a way to be able to return both values. This could be in the form of a code or a formula.

Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Is a VBA function allowed?

Comment: yes it is please

Comment: Array formula:  {=TEXTJOIN(", ",,IF(H$2:H$10=$C2,J$2:J$22,""))}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A Textual Lookup

The scenario when there is an error in the cell where we want to get the value for the string is NOT covered. Anything else should be fine.

In your case you should put the function into a standard module and in Excel for this exact scenario use the following formula in cell **E2** (and copy down):

```
=TLU(C2,H$2:H$5,1)
```

There is additional functionality e.g. the columns can be anywhere (left, right, in the middle), the separator can be changed (the 4th argument by default ", ") and the case sensitivity (5th argument). Play with it.

```vb
Option Explicit

Function TLU(SourceValue As Variant, SourceColumn As Range, _
  ValueColumnOffset As Long, Optional Separator As String = ", ", _
  Optional CaseInSensitive As Long = 1) As String

    Dim ValueColumn As Range  ' Value Column
    Dim vntS As Variant       ' Source Array
    Dim vntV As Variant       ' Value Array

    Dim colSource As Long     ' SourceColumn Column Number
    Dim colTC As Long         ' ThisCell Column Number
    Dim i As Long             ' Source and Value Array Counter
    Dim strS As String        ' Source String
    Dim strR As String        ' Resulting String

    ' Calculate SourceColumn Number.
    colSource = SourceColumn.Column

    ' Calculate Value Column and eliminate some impossible scenarios
    ' using error handling.
    On Error GoTo ProcedureExit
        Set ValueColumn = Cells(SourceColumn.Row, SourceColumn.Column) _
          .Offset(, ValueColumnOffset).Resize(SourceColumn.Rows.Count)
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Calculate ThisCell Column Number
    colTC = Application.ThisCell.Column
    ' Check ThisCell Column Number against SourceColumn Number and
    ' Value Column Number.
    If colTC = colSource Or colTC = ValueColumn.Column Then Exit Function

    ' Write SourceValue to Source String and values of ranges to arrays.
    strS = CStr(SourceValue): vntS = SourceColumn: vntV = ValueColumn

    ' Loop through arrays and build Resulting String.
    For i = 1 To UBound(vntS)
        If StrComp(CStr(vntS(i, 1)), strS, CaseInSensitive) = 0 Then
            If strR <> "" Then
                strR = strR & Separator & vntV(i, 1)
            Else
                strR = vntV(i, 1) ' First value has no separator.
            End If
        End If
    Next

    TLU = strR

ProcedureExit:

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use `Dictionary` object in a VBA function

```
Function GetIctoProducts(ictoID As String) As Variant
    Dim cel As Range

    GetIctoProducts = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    With CreateObject("Scripting.dictionary")
        For Each cel In Range("H2", Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp))
            .Item(cel.Value) = .Item(cel.Value) & cel.Offset(, 2).Value & ", "
        Next

        If .Exists(ictoID) Then GetIctoProducts = Left(.Item(ictoID), Len(.Item(ictoID)) - 2)
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Non-vba solution for Office 365 subscribers.

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER($J$2:$J$10,$H$2:$H$10=$C2))
```